# String to URL swift

Tags: xcode, строки, swift

Как сконвертировать строку "ff\"ff" в NSURL?

Получается так:

```
let str = "ff\"ff"   //ff"ff
let url = NSURL(string: str) //nil
```

А нужно, чтобы print(url) выдавало ff"ff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знак " обозначается как %22, т.е. чтобы получить из String = "ff\"ff" ссылку NSURL = "ff"ff", нужно инициализировать NSURL строкой "ff%22ff".

```
let str = "ff%22ff"
let url = NSURL(string: str)
print(url) // ff"ff
```